# DNS does not resolve in browser or when pinging but does during dig or curl

Tags: networking, dns, amazon-web-services

I'm using GoDaddy as the registrar and Route 53 (AWS) to handle DNS resolution. Route 53 in turn routes to an AWS Elastic Beanstalk node.js application.

The domain resolves to the correct IP address when I use the dig command or curl e.g. `dig liammcnulty.dev` returns:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> liammcnulty.dev
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 12842
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;liammcnulty.dev.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
liammcnulty.dev.    60  IN  A   18.168.186.219

;; Query time: 46 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Oct 06 17:03:57 BST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 64
```

However, I cannot connect via browser (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT) and
`ping liammcnulty.dev` also returns

```
PING liammcnulty.dev (18.168.186.219): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
```

My Route 53 nameservers have been correctly added to GoDaddy so I'm a little bit stumped with this one. Any ideas?

Comment: I pinged the IP address and failed with same message. However I'm able to open your test page `"Liam's dev site - Hello There"` when I put the IP on a browser. So the ping failure is simply caused by the server or firewall protecting it being configured to drop ICMP packets, i.e. not to respond to ping - a common security practice. As browsing to the DNS name fails but to IP address is successful, you have some problem in the DNS. `nslookup` also resolves the DNS name to correct IP, so the problem doesn't seem to be on the DNS record either.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a DNS issue because you can see that when you ping your domain, there is an IP address between parentheses which means your DNS resolution is good.

The problem here is with ping (ICMP). For this to work, you need to allow ICMP on your security group(s).